# SEO: One domain for all languages or domain per language

Tags: seo, internationalization, language

I have a questions for SEO experts. We have an international website catalogue translated into different languages. The cataloue also slightly changes results by user's country (enlisted pages support only users from certain countries and have localization only to certain languages). We have spanish, russian, turkish, slovak and english version.
Which sollution do you consider best?
1. One domain for all versions. xxx.com/en, xxx.com/tr, xxx.com/es, xxx.com/ru
2. Domain per language xxx.com, xxx.es, xxx.tr, xxx.ru, xxx.sk
3. Or even domain per country xxx.es, xxx.cl, xxx.com.ve, xxx.com.mx, xxx.com.ar, etc. 
Currently we have mix of 2. and 3. English domain has specific page for each bigger country (xxx.com/en-US, xxx.com/en-CA). Each page is correctly linked to others with link rel="alternate" hreflang="XY.
Which sollution do you consider better for domain authority. Does rel="alternate" transfer authority in a desired way or you think that it's better to collect authority for only 1 domain?